# What is $[T]^{\scr{C}}_{\scr{B}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

What does it mean for $[T]^{\scr{C}}_{\scr{B}}\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ to be a matrix of $T$ in basis $\scr{B}$ in $\scr{C}$?

Comment: This is a concept available in _every_ textbook on elementary linear algebra. Have you read your text or notes?

Comment: @EuYu I don't think that this is the most obvious concept; maybe his doubt is about the concept itself.

Comment: @GustavoMarra I'm not too sure. The OP doesn't describe what knowledge he has beforehand nor does he talk about what particular aspects of the concept he wants to learn about. This seems analogous to asking for a chapter of some textbook to me.

Comment: My guess is that the OP didn't know how to ask properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are considering $m\times n$ matrices over $F$, so $T$ must be a linear transformation from $F^n$ to $F^m$. It's not clear from your question, but I will assume that
$$\mathscr{B}=\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n\}$$is a basis of $F^n$ and
$$\mathscr{C}=\{\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_m\}$$is a basis of $F^m$. (If it's the other way around, just swap $\scr{B}$ and $\scr{C}$ in the rest of my answer.)

Then the statement that an element $A\in\mathrm{M}_{m\times n}(F)$ is the matrix of $T$ in the bases $\scr{B}$ and $\scr{C}$ just means that
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the $a_{ij}$ are the elements of $F$ uniquely determined by
$$T(\beta_i)=\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}\gamma_j.$$
This uniquely determined element $A$ is denoted $[T]_{\scr{B}}^{\scr{C}}$.

Comment: I think it's usually the other way around; to be consistent with "from $a$ to $b$" in $\int_a^b$ and put the "from" below and the "to" above.

Comment: Ah, fair point - I'll switch the order (I got the order mixed up a few times in my original answer anyway).

Answer (score 2):

$\mathcal{B}$ is some basis for the input space $\mathbb{R}^n$. As a basis, it has a first, second,...,etc. vector.

$\mathcal{C}$ is some basis for the output space $\mathbb{R}^m$. As a basis, it has a first, second,...,etc. vector.

When you have a generic vector $\vec{v}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it has its usual coordinate structure, but it *also* has a column vector structure that respects $\mathcal{B}$. By $[\vec{v}]_{\mathcal{B}}$, we mean a column vector whose $i$th component is a coefficient for the $i$th vector in the basis $\mathcal{B}$. We have set up notation so that $\vec{v}=\sum ([\vec{v}]_{\mathcal{B}})_i\cdot\vec{b}_i$.

Similarly $T\vec{v}=\sum ([T\vec{v}]_{\mathcal{C}})_i\cdot\vec{c}_i$.

And then we introduce a matrix of numerical entries $[T]_\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{C}$ such that $[T]_\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{C}[\vec{v}]_\mathcal{B}$ will work out to be $[T\vec{v}]_\mathcal{C}$. This mimics how $T\vec{v}$ works out to be, well, $T\vec{v}$.

I'm trying to answer what I think you have asked - what is the concept of $[T]_\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{C}$. To find the entries that make up that matrix is a next step.